# segmentation fault - Python -> C

Tags: python, c, gcc, segmentation-fault, cython

My code is:

```
&#35;!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('ls')
```

I converted it to C code using cython:

```
~ $ cython ostest.py
~ $ ls ostest*
ostest.c  ostest.py
```

Then compiled C file using gcc:

```
~ $ gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing \-I/usr/include/python2.7 -o ostest.so ostest.c
~ $ ls ostest*
ostest.c  ostest.py  ostest.so
```

And when I tried to execute the file, its giving error:

```
~ $ ./ostest.so
Segmentation fault
```

I checked the file permissions:

```
~ $ ls -l ostest.so
-rwxr-xr-x
```

The python code I mentioned above is just a sample. I tried doing the same with other python programs I have written. For all of them, I'm getting the same error.
How to solve this?

Comment: Why are you building a shared library?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit which tutorial you are following? This looks very weird. Why are you building a shared library and then try to execute it via shell? That does not make much of a sense.

Comment: I'm trying to create a stand-alone executable file for linux from python code. I'm very new to Linux and Python.

Comment: You don't need to compile python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to execute a shared library (which is what you're building by using the `-shared` flag with GCC) is going to result in a segmentation fault. That's because you're **not meant** to run a shared library. It appears you've misread the instructions for [Cython Compilation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html) -- which clearly states that the command you've used is for compiling extension modules (C code which you can `import` from Python). Cython is **not** for making standalone Python programs, it's for compiling Python extension modules to C. You'll still need to run a Python interpreter to use them.

If you want to compile your Python code to be a standalone binary (whatever that means -- all binaries except statically linked binaries have some dependancy on system libraries), you might want to take a look at this SO question: [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

You can use [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html), which is a Python compiler than can produce standalone executables that I've heard good things about.